# Viewport Render is different from an actual render

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, shadows, hdri

So I was playing with Shader to RGB nodes, however I encountered a slight problem. I used an HDRI in EEVEE to make a simple lighting setup for my wooper, but it seems that the viewport render is different from the one blender actually show

[image]
The rendered wooper

[image]
Viewport wooper

[image]
World shader

I can try and move the sliders on the colorramp which seems to fix the issue, but I'd like to know the reason behind this and a possible solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: First question: is the viewport set up to show the scene lights/world? If not, of course it looks different. Second question: is the "studio009.exr" image a 360° image meant to surround the scene? It should be, since the image texture's projection is set to _Equirectangular_. And if so I would set it to the default _Generated_ texture coordinates, or is there a specific reason you changed that?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann 
1) If you are talking about the rendered view, then yes, you can see that it's active on the 2nd image
2) Yes it's an HDRI downloaded from an HDRI haven. I have changed the texture coordinates, but I doesn't seem like the orientation is the issue. As I've previously mentioned this can be fixed through sliding color ramps or decreasing the value of BG colour strength.

Comment: What I meant was something different, not if rendered view is enabled. In the dropdown menu next to it there are options to enable or disable _Lighting_ > _Scene Lights_ and _Scene World_. By default, the material preview has this turned off, and the rendered view has them turned on. But this can be changed in which case the rendered viewport and the render result can show different lighting, because the render result will always use _Scene Lights_ and _Scene World_, but the rendered viewport does not have to. Or is there maybe some light source disabled in viewport but enabled in render?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Oh wait there was indeed a light source hidden, I'm so dumb. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I should have asked for a screenshot of the _Outliner_, often these issues are easily to be detected there.